# .load ajax not working properly whitin wordpress theme

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I try to use the .load function in my Wordpress theme , the code I use is previously tested in an HTML theme and it worked well .

When I'm using it in the js file of the Wordpress theme, it's display nothing.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

Thank you all in advance

> jQuery and .js are loaded in functions.php

```
function atito_theme_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'atito-theme-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );

wp_enqueue_script( 'atito-theme-jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-2.2.2.min.js', array(), '20130114', true );

wp_enqueue_script( 'atito-theme-atito', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/atito.js', array(), '20130114', true );
}
```

> atito.js

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
jQuery('#auto').load('load.php').fadeIn("slow");
}, 100); // refresh every 100 milliseconds
```

> HTML

```
<div id="auto"></div>
```

> load.php

```
<p>test ajax</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont use `$` on wordpress codes. use only `jQuery`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
jQuery('#auto').load('load.php').fadeIn("slow");
}, 100); // refresh every 100 milliseconds
</script>

<div id="auto"></div>
```

Comment: I have changed it but still no result

Comment: Click F12 and look what is error on site. Open page and press F12 and click console section you will see red errors. Write here what is that.

Comment: When I do that only two errors appears:  **1)**  TypeError: jQuery(...).niceScroll is not a function
 atito.js:38:24
**2)** mutating the [[Prototype]] of an object will cause your code to run very slowly; instead create the object with the correct initial [[Prototype]] value using Object.create player.js:9:28491